# How can I show that two numbers are elements of the same set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am creating a condition for some statement, and need to show that $n$ and $m$ must both be integers, with $n\neq{m}$.

The first time this condition is specified I write it out in full, as above, but it is repeated several times so I would prefer a more succinct way to express it.

I wonder if $n,m\in\mathbb{Z},n\neq{m}$ is correct?

It seems awkward to me to have to commas in such funny places, I'd prefer to use something else if possible.

I thought also that perhaps ${\{n,m\}\subset\mathbb{Z},n\neq{m}}$ is a correct way of expressing this constraint? But I don't have a lot of knowledge about sets and set notation so can't be sure.

How can I succinctly express the constraint given in the first paragraph?

Comment: All of your proposals work fine

Comment: @FelixB. what's the best?

Comment: I use the expression n,m are distinct integers.

Comment: @MorganRodgers why is it not correct? Commas are often used in place of "and" operators, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a succint way, but not an "easy" way, of putting your condition, then you could say $|\{n,m\}|=2$, where the vertical bars indicate the cardinal of the set inside them (since if we had $n=m$ then it would be $|\{n,m\}|=|\{n\}|=1$).

If it is the commas that are bugging you, then you can always intertwine some words between them, as in "for $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n\neq m$".